# Diferencia al retornar el valor?

Tags: javascript

Cuál es la diferencia entre hacer:

```
function b() {
 return function(){return b();}
}
```

versus:

```
function b() {
 return b();
}
```

Es lo mismo o tiene ventajas?, lo he visto en muchas funciones recursivas.

Comment: El segundo código no tiene sentido, es un loop infinito

Comment: Uno regresa una función para usarse, otro manda llamar la misma función dentro de sí misma, haciendo lo que ya comentó el primer comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te dije en mi comentario, el segundo código no tiene mucho sentido. `b()` se llamaría a sí mismo hasta completar el stack del browser o explotar tu computador, lo que ocurra primero.

El primer código, si bien en tu ejemplo tampoco tiene sentido, es una estructura asociada a la programación funcional.

En vez de una función que sume dos números:

```
function suma(a, b) {
  return a+b;
}
```

Puedes hacer **una función que retorne otra función**, la cual se comportará acorde a como la hayas generado. Por ejemplo, mira la siguiente función

```
function sumarle (a) {
  return function(b) { return a+b;  };
}
```

Entonces tú puedes decir "quiero una función que le sume 2 a cualquier cosa que yo le pase". La generas como

```
var sumarle2 = sumarle(2);
```

Y otra que le sume 5 a todo lo que le pases

```
var sumarle5 = sumarle(5);
```

Obviamente también podrías usarlas directamente sin declararlas como variables:

```
   console.log(sumarle(2)(19)); // retorna 21
```

A probar:

```js
function sumarle (a) {
      return function(b) { return a+b;  };
    }

    var sumarle2 = sumarle(2);
    var sumarle5 = sumarle(5);

    console.log(sumarle2(7)); // retorna 9
    console.log(sumarle5(10)); // retorna 15
    
    console.log(sumarle(2)(19)); // retorna 21
```

En el fondo, la idea es que mediante juegos como este puedas hacer composición de funciones. En vez de escribir tú mismo dos funciones para sumar 2+x y 5+x, las obtuviste de una "fábrica de funciones".

Si te pones creativo, podrías hacer una función de suma que devuelva la suma cuando reciba dos parámetros, o devuelva una función cuando sólo recibe uno, lo cual sería [currificar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currificaci%C3%B3n) la suma

Si te llama la atención la programación funcional, ayer leí un artículo muy bien explicado:

https://vmayakumar.wordpress.com/2017/01/17/functional-programing-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente es el mismo código escrito de dos formas distintas, eso es lo mas parecido a un función recursiva.
Una funcion recursiva seria asi:

```
function factorial(num)
{
    if (num < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (num == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
     return (num * factorial(num - 1));
}

var resultado = factorial(8);
document.write(resultado);

// Salida: 40320
```

Un ejemplo de como calcular el factorial de un numero, pero si llamas a la función en si nuevamente se creara un bucle infinito hasta que colapse tu PC.